# Solve $\log_3(3^x+3)\log_3(3^{x+1}+19)=12$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

My approach is to extract those $x$ from those logarithm even though I dun know what should I do next, but unfortunately I still can't extract it. Here is how I do it:
\begin{equation}
 \log_3(3^x+3)\log_3(3^{x+1}+19)=12\\ \Rightarrow 3^{\log_3(3^x+3)\log_3(3^{x+1}+19)}=3^12
\end{equation}
From the above equation I could extract only one from those two namely $(3^x+3)$ or $(3^{x+1}+19)$ using $a^{\log_a{b}}=b$. Please help

Comment: Before even looking on how to solve this, how do you know a closed form must exist? Is this a set problem or something?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose this problem is from my textbook, so I thought there is a solution

Comment: What level study is your textbook? University?

Comment: @A-levelStudent high school hahah

Answer (score 2):

If we ignore those pesky constants in the logs this becomes $x(x+1)=12$ with the obvious solution $x=3$.  The constants will increase the left side, so we must have $x \lt 3$.  If we try $x=2$ the left side becomes $\log_3(12)\log_3(46)\lt 3 \cdot 4 =12$ so $x \gt 2$.  If there isn't an integral solution, there probably isn't a pretty one, so I fed it to [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%283%2C3%5Ex%2B3%29*log%283%2C3%5E%28x%2B1%29%2B19%29%3D12), getting $x \approx 2.8394482194330276320$

Comment: Even Wolfram can't find a close form so I guess that it